# GWT DevMode filling up tmp directory

Tags: gwt

GWT 2.5.1

Anytime running GWT `DevMode` generates a new huge cache file under `/tmp` directory now, consequently the `OS` warns `low disk space`. However, this problem has never popped up in the past.

The file `gwtXXXbyte-cache` (XXX being a long random number) is nearly `1 GB big`. Is it normal?

The cache file is cleaned up automatically after the DevMode session ends. BTW, rebooting the machine doesn't help.

**@EDIT**

In comparison above, running [GWT starter application](http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html) on `DevMode` generates the new cache file about `50 MB size`. Is it oversize, too?

**@EDIT 2**

I modifed GWT UI releated source code and ran `DevMode` again. Later, the new huge cache file `gwtYYYbyte-cache` (YYY being another long random number) was generated with the `same size` as before - exact number of bytes. Any ideas?

**@EDIT 3**

After manual removal of `./gwt-unitCache`, `./war/WEB-INF/deploy` and `./war/ZZZ` directory (ZZZ being the hosted GWT application on `DevMode`), the next `DevMode` session generates the `/tmp/gwtXXXbyte-cache` file shrinking to `a few KB`.

**@EDIT 4**

Launching `DevMode` with the option `-workDir DDD` (DDD being another writable directory) doesn't work. The cached staffs keep writing to the default `/tmp` directory.

Comment: I'm using GWT 2.5.0 and I'm getting a unitcache file of 55.9MB for the  GWT starter App.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973511/what-is-the-gwt-byte-cache-file: "Looking at the gwt source code, it says it's "A global shared Disk cache", used by a linker (com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker package) and compiler (com.google.gwt.dev.javac package)."

Comment: I see this all the time on a Windows 7 dev machine using Eclipse. Periodically, I just flush everything in C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp -- it can be 10s of GB.

Answer (score 4):

1GB is too much for development purposes.
The only reason I can think of is that you have set a lot of **permutations** in your .gwt.xml file.
You should reduce the number of permutations during development to the minimum ( only include the specs you are using).
You can use the **[DevGuideCompileReport](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html)** to locate the problem.

*Edit:*

The **common issue** has been reported by other users. It has to do with the eclipse plugin not deleting the temp files correctly. The issue has been reported and had a lot of attention from GWT users, but no concrete patch has been released. **The workarounds were to manually delete the files or to write a script to do the work for you**:

[google-plugin-for-eclipse-issue74](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5261)

Comment: No, it's on the process of `DevMode`, permutations of statically compiling java source to javascript are not yet involved.

Comment: The problem of mine isn't same, i.e. every new `DevMode` session generates the huge cache file alone, which isn't accumulated by one after another. The end of every `DevMode` session cleans up the cache file `automatically`.

Comment: I'm having same problem, but I'm using Gradle and IntelliJ, so this can't possibly be as simple as a problem with an eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a windows batch script to clean up after GWT:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Cleaning ImageResourceGenerator files ...
IF EXIST "%TEMP%\ImageResourceGenerator*" DEL "%TEMP%\ImageResourceGenerator*" /F /Q

ECHO Cleaning uiBinder files ...
IF EXIST "%TEMP%\uiBinder*" DEL "%TEMP%\uiBinder*" /F /Q

ECHO Cleaning gwt files ...
IF EXIST "%TEMP%\gwt*" DEL "%TEMP%\gwt*" /F /Q

ECHO Cleaning gwt directories ...
FOR /D /R %TEMP% %%x IN (gwt*) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%x"

ECHO.
ECHO Done.
PAUSE
```